# MODX - Access TV's of resource fetched from a ResourceList and display with getImageList

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, template-variables, migx

I'm trying to output template variables from resources input into a MIGX template variable, which references a template variable with an input type of 'Resource List'. Is this possible?

I've got a template variable(TV) in MODX which has an input type of "Resource List", this TV is called 'product_offer'. This resource list has a where clause which states that it can only contain products with a certain template ID.

I then have another TV which has an input type of MIGX. I use this TV to allow one of my resources to select a list of Resources in a template variable. The MIGX TV's form tab JSON is below. This TV is called 'offersList'.

```
[
{"caption":"Product", "fields": [
    {"field":"Product","caption":"Product","inputTV":"product_offer"}
]}
]
```

In one of my chunks i'm using getImageList (snippet that comes with migx) to display the list of resources that I've input into the 'offers_list'. Code snippet below:

```
[[getImageList? 
    &tvname=`offersList`
    &tpl=`StoreCategoryTpl-New`
]]
```

The chunk "StoreCategoryTpl-New" accesses the resources with this specific ID's template variables and displays a number of them. A cut-down snippet of the chunk is below.

```
<div class="product-container">        
        <img src="[[+tv.productImage:phpthumbof=`w=150&h=150&zc=1`]]" alt="Thumb of ([[!getResourceField? &id=`[[+product]]` &field=`pagetitle`]])" />
        <h3>[[+pagetitle]]</h3>
</div>
```

Everywhere else in the site I have used this chunk to output the result of a getResources call, getResources of course can output Template Variables.

Can I access the template variables from the resources I've selected in my 'offersList' MIGX TV and output them in the chunk? I can't find any material for this on the forum or through Google searching.

If not, is the only solution to do this with getResources, and perhaps make a new TV which allows the user to enter in multiple Resource ID's as the value, then feed that into the getResources call (to only get those resources)?

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess, but did you try and set the input TV Type like mentioned here?
https://docs.modx.com/extras/revo/migx/migx.backend-usage

I'd try and set the TV type.

Anyway, in the output chunk, you are trying to access the TVs like you would do with *pdoTools* or *getResources* before. As you would have to set "includeTVs", I guess it is not the default behaviour to read the TVs values from the database.

Yout Attempt to read them with *getResourceField* instead should work, also with the tv.productImage.

One last thing: you're using *phpthumbof*. Try *pthumb* instead, it is the new version and you can use it just like phpthumbof before.